# CTE's- "ERROR:42601:syntax error at the end of the input" on REDSHIFT

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am unable to figure out the problem in the below common table expression query. I'm getting an error message

> ERROR:42601:syntax error at the end of the input.

Can someone help me to find the problem in the query?

Thank You.

```
WITH rpt_1 AS
(SELECT count(*) as cnt, count(distinct memberid) as mem_cnt from table1),

rpt_2 AS
(SELECT count(*) as cnt, count(distinct memberid) as mem_cnt from table2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the temporary tables that you create using the `WITH` keyword. The syntax is like this:

```
with w1 as (select * from sales), w2 as (select * from supplies)
select * from w1; -- You are skipping this part, which is required
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yankee.

Comment: @user9760165 Please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted if it solves your problem. Thanks !